# Count of non-zero values in multiple rows in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I need a count of non-zero variables in pairs of rows.

I have a dataframe that lists density of species found at several sampling points. I need to know the total number of species found at each pair of sampling points. Here is an example of my data:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[111,222,333,444],'minnow':[1,3,5,4],'trout':[2,0,0,3],'bass':[0,1,3,0],'gar':[0,1,0,0]})
>>> df
    ID  bass  gar  minnow  trout
0  111     0    0       1      2
1  222     1    1       3      0
2  333     3    0       5      0
3  444     0    0       4      3
```

I will pair the rows by ID number, so the pair (111,222) should return a total of 4, while the pair (111,333) should return a total of 3. I know I can get a sum of non-zeros for each row, but if I add those totals for each pair I will be double counting some of the species.

Comment: can you post your desired data set?

Comment: The output for each pair will be incorporated into a looping formula, so I could get a single integer variable for each pair and then recalculate it each time the loop repeats. Alternatively, I could calculate all pairs at once and save the output to a dataframe and then pull from that for the calculations in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using iloc for slicing and numpy

```
np.sum((df.iloc[[0, 1], 1:]!=0).any(axis=0))
```

Here df.iloc[[0, 1], 1:] gives you first two rows and numpy sum is counting the total number of non zero pairs in the selected row. You can use df.iloc[[0, 1], 1:] to select any combination of rows.

Comment: This works! I will be able to incorporate it into the loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with NumPy -

```
In [35]: df
Out[35]: 
    ID  bass  gar  minnow  trout
0  111     0    0       1      2
1  222     1    1       3      0
2  333     3    0       5      0
3  444     0    0       4      3

In [36]: a = df.iloc[:,1:].values!=0

In [37]: r,c = np.triu_indices(df.shape[0],1)

In [38]: l = df.ID

In [39]: pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((l[r], l[c], (a[r] | a[c]).sum(1))))
Out[39]: 
     0    1  2
0  111  222  4
1  111  333  3
2  111  444  2
3  222  333  3
4  222  444  4
5  333  444  3
```

Comment: This is giving me an error when I run your line 72: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#77>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((l[r], l[c], (a[r] | a[c]).sum(1))))
NameError: name 'l' is not defined

Comment: @TheresaBrown Sorry, I forgot to add `l = df.ID` then. Just edited. Check it out.

Comment: 1 = df.ID returned an error 'can't assign to literal', I tried replacing 1 with d, but now I'm getting an error that says 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: @TheresaBrown That has to be `l` as in london, not the numeral `one` : `l = df.ID`.

Comment: I'm still getting the 'int object has no attribute 'get_item' error

Comment: @TheresaBrown Try `l = df.ID.values`?

Answer (score 0):

If the rows are sorted so that the two groups occur one after another, you could do

```
import pandas as  pd
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(0,2,(10,3))

df = pd.DataFrame(x)

pair_a = df.loc[::2].reset_index(drop = True)
pair_b = df.loc[1::2].reset_index(drop = True)


paired = pd.concat([pair_a,pair_b],axis = 1)
```

Then find where `paired` is non-zero.